ASP.NET MVC - Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred
Created Login and Register actions, when I test on my local pc everything works great, but when I open deployed app(deploy via render) I have this problem(using only program.cs): (https://i.sstatic.net/lTs4N89F.png)

An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-d29053850aa59e95c283b723bc5fe6cd-4d47f074d095ff47-00


Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
I have already tried with changing environment variable , but its not helping me , please help

What exactly is your question?

All the steps below can help you figure out what happened in your application.

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT this option is not recommended to be enabled in a production environment, as it may leak some privacy information. It can be used to locate problems in a learning or UAT environment.

Generally speaking, when we can see the current prompt page, it means your deployment has been successful.
Most of the time we see this page when there is a problem with the database connection string. So you can check the database connection string to make sure it is accessible through the public network.
If you are using Azure App Service, you can view options such as Application Event Logs in Diagnose and solve problems to troubleshoot the problem.
If not using azure app service, we can enable asp.net core logging feature to check more details. Or we can enable stdoutLogEnabled="true" if we are using windows platform web server.

As to why it happens - check your Program.cs - there should be something among these line:
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Which will display detailed information about exception when such exception happens.
Without this developer page, upon exception you will get what you see, which is correct behavior (exception details are considered sensitive data).
Why this works like that? Most probably because you have
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

Which will enable this page only when running in development mode (on local machine, unless you specify ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development on other machines.
In order to further debug your problem, you must go into logs to look for exception details.
